# Custom route to handle authorized users?

Tags: reactjs, express

I would like to create a custom express route that would allow to determine if a user has the right to access a page or not.

So far I got it working by using something like that :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AuthenticationContext } from '../../contexts/authentication/context';

import Unauthorized from '../Unauthorized';

import axios from 'axios';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, redirect: Redirect, contextProvider: ContextProvider, path, ...routeProps }) => {

  const { authenticationState: {isAuthenticated, isFetchingTheUser, currentUser} } = React.useContext(AuthenticationContext)

  const [authorized, setAuthorized] = React.useState([]);
  const [isFetchingAuthorizations, setIsFetchingAuthorizations] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {

    setIsFetchingAuthorizations(true);
    axios.get(`${global.REST_API_ADDR}/api/pages/${encodeURIComponent(path)}`)
    .then((response) => {
      setAuthorized(response.data.authorized);
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setIsFetchingAuthorizations(false);

      // console.log("Protected route use Effect error : ", error);
    })
  }, [path])


  return (
    <Route {...routeProps}
      render={ props => {

        if(isFetchingTheUser || isFetchingAuthorizations) return <div>Chargement...</div>

        if(isAuthenticated && authorized.includes(currentUser.rank)){
          return ContextProvider ? <ContextProvider><Component {...props} /></ContextProvider> : <Component {...props} />
        }else if(isAuthenticated && !authorized.includes(currentUser.rank)) {
          return <Unauthorized {...props} />;
        }
        else{
          return <Redirect {...props}/>;
        }
    }}/>
  );

};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

The problem here is that if the user changes routes a second time, the component will keep the previous authorized array for a few milliseconds, render the component and if the component has any kind of
useEffect with some API calls it will throw an error in the console. I would like to know if there is any way to prevent this ? 
Like maybe emptying the state after the route renders the component ?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT 1 : from the user's point of view there are no visual bugs or latency but as a developer I have a hard time leaving an error message in the console if there is any way to avoid it

Comment: I don't get why you are handling authorized routes in the client ... you can just block the access to this route in your express app and serve a non authorized page

Comment: Since my project is not meant to be public i'm using CSR (client-side rendering) because the only pro of using SSR (server-side rendering) is to be CEO friendly.